# How do I add a new meeting request to an Outlook calendar using interop?

Tags: c#, interop, outlook

Ok, I am trying to connect to a shared Outlook Calendar in C# using Interop and add a new meeting request.

Here's what I've got so far, starting with my using statements (this is a Windows form):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

Then I have a public class called "Appointments" which is below:

```
public class Appointments
{
    public string ConversationTopic { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public string Organizer { get; set; }
    public int ReminderMinutesBeforeStart { get; set; }
    public string RequiredAttendees { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

I have a new blank windows form with a Data Grid View currently called dataGridView1. The form load event code is below:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Outlook.Application oApp;
    oApp = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");
    oNS.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true, true);

    Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oNS.CreateRecipient("Foo bar");
    Outlook.MAPIFolder oFolder = (Outlook.MAPIFolder) oNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(oRecip, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

    List<Appointments> appointmentList = new List<Appointments>();

    foreach (object item in oFolder.Items)
    {
        Outlook.AppointmentItem thisOne = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)item;
        appointmentList.Add(new Appointments { ConversationTopic = thisOne.ConversationTopic, Duration = thisOne.Duration, EndTime = thisOne.End, Organizer = thisOne.Organizer, ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = thisOne.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart, RequiredAttendees = thisOne.RequiredAttendees, StartTime = thisOne.Start, Subject = thisOne.Subject, Body = thisOne.Body });
    }

    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = appointmentList;
    dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns["Subject"], ListSortDirection.Descending);
}
```

This works flawlessly in connecting to my calendar and filling my Data Grid View with all of my relevant calendar information. Now I want to programmatically send a new Meeting Request to the calendar.

I'm guessing a Meeting Request is an oFolder.Item so I think I want to type:

```
oFolder.Items.Add(* details here *);
```

Inside the brackets, intellisense simply says the following:

> dynamic_Items.Add([object Type = Type.Missing])

Now I'm stumped and help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;    

private void SetRecipientTypeForAppt()
    {
        Outlook.AppointmentItem appt =
            Application.CreateItem(
            Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)
            as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
        appt.Subject = "Customer Review";
        appt.MeetingStatus = Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;
        appt.Location = "36/2021";
        appt.Start = DateTime.Parse("10/20/2006 10:00 AM");
        appt.End = DateTime.Parse("10/20/2006 11:00 AM");
        Outlook.Recipient recipRequired =
            appt.Recipients.Add("Ryan Gregg");
        recipRequired.Type =
            (int)Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olRequired;
        Outlook.Recipient recipOptional =
            appt.Recipients.Add("Peter Allenspach");
        recipOptional.Type =
            (int)Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olOptional;
        Outlook.Recipient recipConf =
           appt.Recipients.Add("Conf Room 36/2021 (14) AV");
        recipConf.Type =
            (int)Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olResource;
        appt.Recipients.ResolveAll();
        appt.Display(false);
    }
```

via How to: [Create a Meeting Request, Add Recipients, and Specify a Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb644964.aspx)

Comment: So do you think I need to create one of these objects (an Outlook.AppointmentItem object) build it as described above and then use oFolder.Items.Add(appt)?

Comment: No, you will call oApp.CreateItem(...), you can then call save on the appointment object to save it to the calendar.  No need to use the Folder.Add method.

Comment: @JohnKoerner Thanks, if the appointment slot isn't available and I try to call save on the appointment object, will it throw an error that I can catch?

Comment: @JohnKoerner Ok, so I guess I need to check that the DateTime of the appointment I wish to add is present in my list first before I call save?