# How do I access an Outlook user's calendar using C#?

Tags: c#, outlook

I want to access the appointments in an Outlook user's calendar, given the user's email address.

This presumably involves somehow using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace` object to get to the user's calendar.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90899/net-get-all-outlook-calendar-items

Comment: Maybe these will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216064/connect-to-outlook-calendar-from-c-sharp-using-interop and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217396/how-do-i-add-a-new-meeting-request-to-an-outlook-calendar-using-interop

Comment: @JesseJames, that's a different question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @JMK - it looks like that second question deals with my situation.

Comment: @JMK, the answer is embedded in the question you posted, but if you wanted to post a targeted answer here I don't think it'd be unreasonable. Then again, I'm not a moderator. In the mean time I've posted an answer.

Comment: @mackenir Your answer more or less covers my understanding of Outlook Interop (I haven't spent a lot of time on it), no point in me posting a duplicate!

Answer (score 5):

Here is the specific code snippet for opening a particular user's calendar, taken from the question posted in the comments on this question, by **JMK**:

```
string userName = "Foo bar";

Outlook.Application oApp;
oApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");
oNS.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true, true);

Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oNS.CreateRecipient(userName);
Outlook.MAPIFolder usersCalendarFolder = (Outlook.MAPIFolder) oNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(oRecip, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
```