# What are the ways to access outlook Calendar?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, outlook, oauth-2.0

I only found the one with the Outlook REST Api which uses oauth2, but I am using wcf soap and can't use that option.Is there another way to access the calendar(via username/password or something else)?
Edit:
The problem is that I only have a web service and no UI.

Comment: [Exchange WebServices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx) Is a very useful API to use.

Comment: This may help.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12369399/2672863